# How to temporarily disable hover during a .animate command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to code a central navigation that allows for 4 tiles to appear from behind an image when the image is clicked. I am having an issue in which the tiles have a CSS styling of hover that can interrupt their toggle animation and wondered how I could temporarily disable the hover while the animation is running.

https://jsfiddle.net/Destinneh/4tgs2L5y/10/

http://sendvid.com/xodtv69a A video of what I'm trying to avoid.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("trigger")==="0"){
        $('#navDown').animate({"top":"90%"},600);
        $('#navUp').animate({"top":"10%"},600);
        $('#navRight').animate({"left":"10%"},600);
        $('#navLeft').animate({"left":"90%"},600);
        $(this).attr("trigger","1");
}
else{
        $('#navUp').animate({"top":"50%"},600);
        $('#navDown').animate({"top":"50%"},600);
        $('#navLeft').animate({"left":"50%"},600);
        $('#navRight').animate({"left":"50%"},600);
        $(this).attr("trigger","0");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can introduce new class
- Use it to play with hover
- Remove class when you start animation
- Add class back when animation ends

For example, change JS code to code below:

```
const navIds = ['#navDown', '#navUp', '#navRight', '#navLeft'];

function onAnimateStart() {
  for (const id of navIds) {
    $(id).removeClass('hoverOn');
  }
}

function onAnimateComplete() {
  for (const id of navIds) {
    $(id).addClass('hoverOn');
  }
}

$('#button').click(function() {
  onAnimateStart();
  if ($(this).attr("trigger")==="0") {
    $('#navDown').animate({"top":"90%"}, 600);
    $('#navUp').animate({"top":"10%"}, 600);
    $('#navRight').animate({"left":"10%"}, 600);
    $('#navLeft').animate({"left":"90%"}, 600, function() {
      onAnimateComplete()
    });
    $(this).attr("trigger","1");
  } else {
    $('#navUp').animate({"top":"50%"}, 600);
    $('#navDown').animate({"top":"50%"}, 600);
    $('#navLeft').animate({"left":"50%"}, 600);
    $('#navRight').animate({"left":"50%"}, 600, function() {
      onAnimateComplete();
    });
    $(this).attr("trigger","0");
  }
});
```

Change CSS part

```
.centreNav:hover{
    transition: 0.25s;
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    border:2px solid white;
}
```

To:

```
.hoverOn:hover {
    transition: 0.25s;
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

HTML part to (basically add hoverOn to your `centreNav` elements):

```
<div id="containerCent">
  <a id="button" trigger="0" href="#"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt=" logo"></a>           

  <div id="spiralNav">
    <a href="#">
      <div id="navUp" class="centreNav hoverOn">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <div id="navLeft" class="centreNav hoverOn">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div id="navRight" class="centreNav hoverOn">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <div id="navDown" class="centreNav hoverOn">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle with all changes from above:
https://jsfiddle.net/g3p2erfo/